# Not getting FCM push notification when app is killed by the user

Tags: ios, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase for push notification on iOS using swift 4.2. When App is killed,, push notifications are not working. What should I need to do to make it work.

Comment: you have configured in background modes, remote notifications? can you put your appDelegate?

Comment: yes, i have remote mode and notification configured. I am not getting push notification in app delegate when app is killed

Comment: Are the certificates created and loaded in the firebase panel?

Comment: yes, certs are created and Push Notification is working when app is on or in background. Only issue is when app is killed, no push notification.

Comment: When the app is killed you won't receive silent notifications.  Users swiping up apps is an unfortunate habit that many have, but it tells iOS that they don't want your app to run.

Comment: When the app is not running, the Push Notifications are received by the OS and handled as required. Only thing is that, for the OS to display the Notification, the body of the notification must have aps:{body: value,badge: value,sound: value}.